# Is the rabbit constant the first natural math constant found to be non-normal?

Tags: probability, number-theory, statistics

The rabbit constant (related to Fibonacci numbers), as well as proof of its non-normalcy, is discussed in one of my recent articles, [here](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/some-fun-with-the-golden-ratio-time-series-and-number-theory). One might argue that it is a semi-artificial number. I was wondering if besides that number, and excluding artificial numbers such as $0.100111100000000111\ldots$, other irrational math constants are known to be non-normal (that is, with a digit distribution that is not uniform.)

Comment: With $R = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-\lfloor n \phi \rfloor}$, $\phi=(1+\sqrt{5})/2$ then isn't it obvious it is non normal, since $\phi \in (1,2)$ means it doesn't have any $00$ in its binary expansion ?

Comment: It is rather obvious, for a number of reasons, that it is not normal in base 2. What is less obvious is that these digits are also not normal in any base $b \in ]1, 2[$. In such as base, the distribution of the digits (if you pick up a number at random) is not uniform, and digits are negatively auto-correlated. The distribution of the digits and auto-correlations, in that case, depend on $b$, but not on the number itself if it is a "normal" number. The same is true for any number that is derived from the Beatty sequence using the same construct.